How to call again a function when I change the value of the input when I click on button?
I wanted to build the Fibonacci sequence using DOM. I used an input where you type a number and then result the last number of the sequence and then display all the sequence. The problem is when I want to change the number from the input, it continues to display the next sequence instead of changing the previous one and also continues with "Type a positive number." if I type a negative number, keeping the previous sequence. I want to cancel the previous results and run the function again when I change the number from the input and click on the button, but I don't understand how to do it.


var btn1 = document.querySelector('#btn1');                
var input = document.querySelector('#input');            
var span1 = document.querySelector('#span1');           
var span2 = document.querySelector("#span2");           
var para1 = document.querySelector('#para1');          
var para2 = document.querySelector('#para2');        
var list = document.querySelector('#list');           
btn1.addEventListener('click', fibonacci);

function fibonacci() {

if(input.value <= 0) {
para1.textContent = 'Type a positive number.';
para2.remove();
}

if (input.value == 1) {
span1.textContent = 1;
span2.textContent = 1;
list.textContent = '1';
}

if (input.value == 2) {
span1.textContent = 2;
span2.textContent = 1;
list.textContent = '1, 1'
}

if (input.value >= 3) {
let array = [1, 1];
span1.textContent = input.value;

for (let i = 2; i < input.value; i++) {
var item = array[i-2] + array[i-1];
array.push(item);
};

span2.textContent = array[input.value-1]

for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.textContent = array[j];
list.appendChild(li);


input.focus();
}
<label for = 'number'>Type a number: </label>
<input type = 'number' id = 'input'>
<button id = 'btn1'>Click me</button>
<p id = 'para1'>The <span id = 'span1'>_</span> number from the sequence is: 
<span id = span2></span></p>
<p id = 'para2'>Your fibonacci sequence is: 
<ul id = 'list'></ul> </p>
</div>




just add list.innerHTML = ''; right inside function fibonacci() {

@GrafiCode Don't use innerHTML if you don't have to as it has security and performance implications. Since the string contains no HTML, there's no need for that. Use textContent instead.

Correct your errors and try again.

@ScottMarcus using innerHTML to set an empty value has no security implications. It just empties the element's contents.

@GrafiCode It makes no difference what you (as the developer) are setting the string to. If that string is available to external sources, you've got a security issue. Also, performance suffers by initiating the DOM parser when that is not needed.

@ScottMarcus what are you talking about? "If that string is available to external sources" what? Man, this is it: element.innerHTML = ''; no security issues whatsoever. Also, "performance suffers by initiating the DOM parser when that is not needed" again, what? Emptying an element assining innerHTML to an empty string is common practice.

@GrafiCode I would recommend you read about innerHTML. It doesn't matter what the string that you are setting is, the DOM parser will be invoked in an attempt to parse any HTML in the string. Assigning an empty string to innerHTML may be common, but it's wrong. And, while in this case, the string doesn't represent a security concern (as it is 100% controlled by the developer), when it is not, there is a potential for opening an attack vector. So don't use innerHTML when there is no HTML. Use textContent instead.

Your code has some errors. I have corrected them for you.

I want to cancel the previous results and run the function again when
I change the number from the input and click on the button, but I
don't understand how to do it.

You need to check the incoming value. from the input text box for whether the value entered is less than zero ( meaning it is a negative value ) if so clear out the values that were displayed earlier while looping through HTML. If the value incoming is a non-negative value proceed with displaying the Fibonacci sequence accordingly.
Refer the code below:


var btn1 = document.querySelector('#btn1');
        var input = document.querySelector('#input');
        var span1 = document.querySelector('#span1');
        var span2 = document.querySelector('#span2');
        var para1 = document.querySelector('#para1');
        var para2 = document.querySelector('#para2');
        var list = document.querySelector('#list');
        
        btn1.addEventListener('click', fibonacci);

        

function fibonacci() {
            para1.textContent = 'The _ number from the sequence is:';
            span1.textContent = '_';
            span2.textContent = '';
            list.innerHTML = '';

            var value = parseInt(input.value);

            if (value <= 0) {
                para1.textContent = 'Type a positive number.';
                return;
            }

            if (value === 1) {
                span1.textContent = 1;
                span2.textContent = 1;
                list.textContent = '1';
                return;
            }

            if (value === 2) {
                span1.textContent = 2;
                span2.textContent = 1;
                list.textContent = '1, 1';
                return;
            }

            let array = [1, 1];
            span1.textContent = value;

            for (let i = 2; i < value; i++) {
                var item = array[i - 2] + array[i - 1];
                array.push(item);
            }

            span2.textContent = array[value - 1];

            array.forEach(num => {
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.textContent = num;
                list.appendChild(li);
            });

            input.focus();
}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fibonacci Sequence</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for='number'>Type a number: </label>
    <input type='number' id='input'>
    <button id='btn1'>Click me</button>
    <p id='para1'>The <span id='span1'>_</span> number from the sequence is: <span id='span2'></span></p>
    <p id='para2'>Your Fibonacci sequence is:</p>
    <ul id='list'></ul>
</body>
</html>



